# Undefined Control Sequences

Tags: pdftex, eplain

I am writing a fairly long paper (150+ pages) in PDF TeX using eplain. In the last ten pages I am getting error messages to the effect that control sequences are undefined.

These are control sequences that have been defined for sure, for I have used them without problem earlier in the paper.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your control sequences are `\invisible` to us ;-)

Comment: **Debugging Tip:**  Put a `\end{document}` right at the point where the errors started occurring.   Verify you get a good compile.  Now move the `\end{document}` forward about a page.  If the compile is good then repeat.  Else if you have errors then you have narrowed the problem to fewer lines.  Now just move the end statement about 1/2 way back compile and repeat until you find the offending line.   **Hint:** Look for forgotten `}` which can play havoc with the compile.

Comment: R. Schumacher: `\end{document}` in eplain? ;-)

Comment: **revised debugging tip:** put `\bye` at the point where the errors start occurring.  this is the `eplain` equivalent of latex's `\end{document}`.  otherwise, the suggestions by @R.Schumacher regarding navigating through the problem area are good.

Comment: It is impossible to say anything with the question in this form, please show the exact error from the log from `!` to `?` in a code `{}` section in the question so line breaks are preserved.